# Is it legal in Germany to start a project in Kickstarter while working in a company?

Tags: germany, startup, legal, employees, law

I live in Germany and have an idea to start my own business here. However, I am not sure whether I am allowed to do this while working officially in a company. I just want to share my project on Kickstarter and see whether people either like or invest in it or not.
Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Unless you are comfortable navigating legal issues on your own, I strongly suggest you talk to a professional specialising in **local** labor and employment laws. These things vary based on a lot of factors.

Comment: There is a difference between legal, and if your company allows you to do it.

Comment: *"I just want to share my project on Kickstarter and see whether people either like or invest in it or not."* This doesn't really have anything to do with your question, but kickstarter doesn't work that way. Few people browses through kickstarter looking for random projects to throw money at. And if they do, then the only projects they get shown are those which already do well. If you want a crowdfunding campaign to succeed, you need to spend a lot of work into generating hype for your product outside of the platform. Preferably long before you even announce that you are going to kickstarter.

Comment: I would seriously caution the author from using Kickstarter, at least the way they describe their plans to use it, there will be a assumption for the author to actually deliver.

Comment: @Donald: Delivering is only an expectation _if_ the investment goal has been met. As far as I see, the OP only expressed uncertainty about reaching the investment goal - not about the ability to deliver, so I'm not surr what you're responding to.

Answer (score 11):

You are allowed to have a business or be self-employed, whether you are a fulltime employee or not.

*However*,

- It is very likely your company reserves the right to know. They might have worded it as if they need to approve it, but courts have ruled that they cannot deny approval without a valid reason. But it is very likely your contract says you need to inform them. If they see that your performance dropped significantly since you started your side business, they will object.
- Your company can deny you taking a side job if it is a conflict of interest. If you are working at a software company and plan to sell christmas sweaters, that doesn't seem to be a conflict for example. Unless your software enables the company to sell their christmas sweaters, then it is a problem. Only you and your company can determine whether your side business is a conflict.
- Read your contract carefully. Some shady contracts say that *anything* you do while working for the company is their intellectual property. While that would never hold up in court if it's obvious it has nothing to do with your work, if it is in your contract, you are the person who has to pay a lawyer and get justice. It might be easier to get that out of your contract *before* there is any real money involved.
- You need to find out if you need to be self-employed or found a company for your side business. For taxt purposes and liability purposes. You may want to ask a tax accountant.

Comment: This gets an upvote from me - particularly points 3 and 4. If your company have not outlined such disclosure your contract (I have had this outlined in my contract in past employment), then they don't need to know. Just ensure you don't work on your idea during your contracted hours and it sounds like you'll be fine.

Comment: @rotisiv The permission for side jobs is in German labor laws, it has nothing to do with your work contract. The right to know applies regardless of what is or isn't in the contract.